# How to increment same set of numbers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have following scenario.

I have numbers grouped by 8 same values and then I want next 8 values to raise by 1.

Example:

```
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
```

I tried few suggestions, but I can't get it to work. :(

When I just drag selected values, it does the work, but ads few extra values.

Comment: Use `=const1+INT((ROW()+const2)/8)`. For example while starting from A1 const1=3, const2=7.

Comment: Working like a charm. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `=INT((ROW(E1)-1)/5)+1`

In the formula, the number 5 indicates to increment the numbers every 5 rows, you can change it to your need

**Edit:**

These formulas was advised by Duke Bouvier: `INT((ROWS(E1:E$1)-1)/8)+1`  and `INT((ROWS(E1:E$1)-1)/8)+1` each one avoids to hard-code the starting line number into the formula. Thank you Duke.

Comment: You can refine this to 

     INT((ROW(E1)-ROW(E$1)/8)+1 

which avoids having to hard-code the starting line number into the formula, or  similarly 

     INT((ROWS(E1:E$1)-1)/8)+1

Comment: @DukeBouvier Your suggested formulas was included in the answer.

Comment: @Duke Bouvier 
Thank you. = INT((ROWS(C1382:C$1382)-1)/8)+1 
I don't know if I managed to figure out those formulas in the meantime, but yours worked from first try.

Thank you Haroldo as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is (as per picture) just use a very standard increment formula but with references to a cell 8 cells above rather than 1 cell above. You can then extend it down as far as you want by copying the last cell or dragging the handle on the bottom right of the cell that you can see when it is selected.

[image]